# C/C++ most efficient if statement evaluation

Tags: c++, c, gcc, if-statement, branch-prediction

X is true nearly 99.9% of the time but I need to handle Y and Z as well.  Although the body of the X condition is empty, I'm thinking it should be faster than potentially checking 2 other conditions Y and Z if the X condition is omitted. What do you think?

```
if (likely(X))
{
}
else if (unlikely(Y))
{
...
}
else if (unlikely(Z))
{
...
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you need to worry about this ?

Comment: The answer depends on your logic. Does condition X *always* imply not-Y and not-Z?

Comment: @PaulR because it's in a very very tight loop.

Comment: And you've profiled it ?

Comment: @PaulR was the question "do i need to worry about this?" or "what's the fastest way to do this?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might want to know what exactly happens when you use likely or unlikely:
http://kerneltrap.org/node/4705

I would personally write

```
if (unlikely(!X))
{
  if (unlikely(Y))
  {
  ...
  }
  else if (unlikely(Z))
  {
   ...
  }
}
```

Which means if `x`, continue execution, else **jump** to if body.

Answer (score 8):

As usual, when in doubt profile; anyhow, if I were to read that code I would find much clearer something like:

```
if (!likely(X))
{
    if (unlikely(Y))
    {
    ...
    }
    else if (unlikely(Z))
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not really sure that the negation of unlikely will work as expected ?? I would rather write `unlikely(!x)`. This means that there will be no jump if `x` is false.

Comment: @Ugo I like the solution posted by Matteo and I rewrote it using your unlikely(!x) instead.

Comment: @Ugo: I assumed that `likely(X)` was the whole condition to be evaluated, as in his pseudocode... still, the point I'm making should be clear.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: `likely` and `unlikely` are macros provided by GCC that wraps compiler specific builtins that *hint* to the compiler whether a condition is likely or not. (gcc's is `__builtin_expect` I think)

Answer (score 1):

If a compiler is to assume, it would generally favor the first condition true.

you can use something like `__builtin_expect` to control this (as Ugo detailed).

If it's in a loop, you should measure because hardware is also a consideration -- it's not just the source and the compiler. How's your cache, and how's branch prediction working for you? Profile. Alter. Profile. Compare.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the unlikely's on y and z? It sounds from your question like if x is not true, then y or z must be true, in which case those unlikely's are incorrect and I would go with this:

```
if (unlikely(!X))
{
  if (Y)
  {
  ...
  }
  else //Z must be true
  {
   ...
  }
}
```

(Would have made this a comment on Ugo's answer, but I don't have enough reputation to leave comments.)